# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running Android UI test with WireMockRule

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, ui-automation, wiremock

I have spent quite some time trying to figure out how to fix this error while running Android Espresso test with WireMock.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor

**The error happens at this line of code:**

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8080));
```

**My build.grade**

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0") {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava'
}

androidTestImplementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1")
```

**More log:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor;
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:695)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpClientFactory.createClient(HttpClientFactory.java:76)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ProxyResponseRenderer.<init>(ProxyResponseRenderer.java:58)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.buildStubRequestHandler(WireMockApp.java:131)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:73)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:43)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:39)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it myself by using wiremock stand-alone version instead.

```
androidTestImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.26.3"
```

Comment: Thank you for the self-answer, this worked for me also.